# How to display video streaming using ffplay in the JavaCV 0.3 Stream Test Android Project?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp, javacv

JavaCV 0.3 Stream Test Android Project can be downloaded [here](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/).
And it is description is in the article ["Android Live Streaming courtesy of JavaCV and FFMPEG"](http://www.walking-productions.com/notslop/2013/01/16/android-live-streaming-courtesy-of-javacv-and-ffmpeg/)

If I want to use ffplay to display the streaming video in the local Internet, I find that it does not work.
 I tried different formats of the ffmpeg_link, such as:
 rtmp://192.168.1.27:1935/livestream/12070660
 rtmp://live:live@192.168.1.27:8080/live/test.flv
 rtmp://192.168.1.27:1935

I use ffplay to display:
 ffplay rtmp://192.168.1.27:1935/livestream/12070660

The output error is:
 RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 113 (No route to host)/0
 rtmp://192.168.1.27:1935/livestream/12070660: Unknown error occurred

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me:

- Use **Wowza** or **Nginx** server
- Change the **ffmpeg_link** in the MainActivity according to the server ip address
- use that same rtmp **ffmpeg_link** to play the live video streaming in **VLC** player or other rtmp players.